# How Can I Close a Second Form?

Tags: c#

How can I close a second Form from another form in C#?

I use this in Form1, but it does not work.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form2.Close();
```

What's wrong??

Comment: You need to close the instance that you `Show()`ed.

Comment: That code makes a new instance of the second form, then closes it. Note that you never call `form2.Show()` or `form2.ShowDialogue()`, so the form will never be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably at some point in time that first form created an instance of type `Form2` and showed it.  It then discarded that reference.  Instead of throwing that reference away you should store it in an instance field of `Form1` so that you can access it later and close it:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 child;
    private void PlaceWhereForm2IsShown()
    {
        child = new Form2();
        child.Show();
    }
    private void CloseForm2()
    {
        child.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By *second form* it appears that the form is **already open**, you need to get instance of that form and then close it. You can use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property which will give you all the opened forms. Get the one you need and close it.

```
var form2 = Application.OpenForms["Form2"] as Form2;
if (form2 != null)
    form2.Close();
```

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment ?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this looks dirty. Not saying it's wrong though.

Comment: @gunr2171, If the form is not opened from the current form, and current form doesn't have the instance, then it is something very useful in WinForm applications.

Comment: I understand, this does sound useful in that instance, but if you find yourself in that situation, you are probably doing something wrong. Upvote to offset.